# Merging Null int Column after joining

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I want to merge, outer join the column "Count" from View_AssessmentCount list to View_Assessment. Of course Count will get an error because it is **int** and I wrote String.Empty. It's at this part where I specify where to outer join the **null** column "Count". But then again I don't know the right terms to Google this. Please help me expound on this.

```
public class AssessmentWithCount
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public String AssessmentName { get; set; }
    public String AssessmentInitials { get; set; }
    public Int16 id { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<AssessmentWithCount> GetAssessmentWithCount()
{
    using (var context = new SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1())
    {
        var query = from a in context.View_Assessment
                    join b in context.View_AssessmentCount on a.AssessmentName equals b.AssessmentName into ab
                    from subA in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new AssessmentWithCount
                    {
                        AssessmentName = a.AssessmentName,
                        Count =  (subA == null ? String.Empty : subA.Count.ToString())
                    };
        return query;
    }
}
```

**Updated post**

Now my error is "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." when I DataBind this class. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert the database field to a string - just use it as-is:

```
Count = (subA == null ? 0 : (subA.Count ?? 0))
```

Regarding the error message... the `using` statement disposes your instance of `SQL_TA_SCOREBOARDEntities1`, so you need to get your data now, before leaving the method:

```
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes I'm getting closer to understanding this better! But now it says cannot implicitly convert "int?" to "int". :(

Comment: Oh allow nulls yes. Also regarding this issue is not clear to me, error handling when fields are nullable. What do I do next? :(

Comment: Sorry wrong choice of words, but anyway thanks! It works perfectly now. All that's left for me is to display "Assessment not counted" instead of "0".

Answer (score 0):

Here try this instead:

```
Count = SubA.Count ?? 0
```

Just had some issues like these and got help. :)
Sorry I can't comment as I have less than 50 reps.